# Automatic switching between ethernet and 4G on router?

Tags: router, ethernet, asus

I have a router which have both incoming internet through Ethernet and 4G via USB. My fiber connection is unstable, and I have gotten a courtesy 4G SIM from my ISP. Is it possible to set up the router in such a way that when fiber connection fails, it automatically switches to 4G?

I have an ASUS 2900 router and an open 4G USB stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reading the manual for [Asus RT-AC2900](https://www.asus.com/Networking/RT-AC2900/HelpDesk_Manual/)? A quick search for *failover* gives:

> 4.3.2 Dual WAN
>
> Your ASUS wireless router provides dual WAN support. You can set the
>   dual WAN feature to any of these two modes:
>
> - **Failover Mode**: Select this mode to use the secondary WAN as  the backup network access.
> - **Load Balance Mode**: Select this mode to optimize bandwidth, minimize response time and prevent data overload for both primary and secondary
>     WAN connections.

The failover mode seems like the feature you are looking for.